# 3D camera local axis rotation

Tags: java, 3d, camera, rotation

I've been working on a 3d software renderer in Java for the past few weeks and I successfully implemented rotations using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations

This rotation will rotate an object around the global x, y, and z axes.  How do I rotate around the camera's local axes?

For example, when looking up / down in 3d you simply rotate the world around the camera's x axis.  This is a problem when the camera is rotated 90 degrees around its y axis (facing the global x axis direction) because then you would want to rotate around the global z axis for the correct effect.

It seems like I need to implement axis-angle rotation but the Wikipedia page and other tutorials I've found (the best one so far: http://www.engr.uvic.ca/~mech410/lectures/4_2_RotateArbi.pdf) are hard to understand.

Edit:
Picture to clarify:
[image: The Problem]

So once again, how do I always rotate about the "local" axis (including when the local axis doesn't match up with the global axis [like when the rotation is 45degrees])

Comment: Are you implementing arbitrary rotation like a plane can move any any direction or like a person moving around who doesn't change his vertical angle.

Comment: @11thdimension arbitrary rotation.
I have included a picture in the above post to clarify the problem as well.

Comment: Checkout `Computer Graphics by Hearn and Baker, Chapter Two Dimensional Geometric Transformation` Here's an online link http://www.slideshare.net/akbrightfuture/computer-graphics-hearn-baker , chapter starts at slide 193. Here's the link for 3D transformation matrices http://web.iitd.ac.in/~hegde/cad/lecture/L6_3dtrans.pdf

Comment: @11thdimension http://web.iitd.ac.in/~hegde/cad/lecture/L6_3dtrans.pdf#10 that's what I was looking for, thanks.